# Как вывести через XDocument элементы списка вложенного в другой список?

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс `Element` со свойствами `ID`, `Type` и т.д. (простые типы). Внутри этого класса также имеется свойство `List<int> TextBoxValue`. У меня много объектов класса `Element` и я храню их все в другом списке `List<Element> Elements`. Для наглядности, приведу приблизительную  иерархию:

- Класс `Element`

  - `ID`
  - `Type`
  - `List<int> TextBoxValue`
- `List<Element> Elements`

  - `Element1` (Объект класса `Element`)
  - `Element2` (Объект класса `Element`)
  - и т.д.

И я хочу вывести все элементы списка `List<Element> Elements` со всеми данными в XML файл. Конечный файл должен выглядеть  подобным образом:

```
<environment>
  <element type="some_type1" id="some_id1">
    <field value="some_value_1" />
    <field value="some_value_2" />
  </element>
  <element type="some_type2" id="some_id2">
    <field value="some_value_3" />
  </element>
  <element type="some_type1" id="some_id3">
    <field value="some_value_4" />
    <field value="some_value_5" />
    <field value="some_value_6" />
  </element >
  <!---etc------->
</environment>
```

Я решил впервые использовать `XDocument` для этого. В целом, все удобно и красиво, кроме одного момента: когда мне нужно вывести все элементы `TextBoxValue`. Я написал следующий код:

```
XDocument xDocument =
                new XDocument(
                new XElement("environment",
                             Elements.Select(x => new XElement("element", new XAttribute("type", x.Type),
                                                                          new XAttribute("id", x.Id),

                                                 new XElement("field", new XAttribute("value", x.TextBoxValue))))
                                )
                             );
```

Здесь `x.TextBoxValue` очевидно написан мной неправильно и, соответственно, выводит совсем не то, что хотелось бы. Но я не знаю что написать в этом месте. Я нашел как сделать селект для первого списка, но как сделать селект списка вложенного в список в данном случаее? Обычно я такие вещи делаю через `foreach`, но тут такого не получится.

Comment: Возможно, в вашем случае будет удобнее использовать сериализацию

Comment: Но если по сути вопроса — вам надо использовать [конструктор, принимающий массив](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XElement__ctor_System_Xml_Linq_XName_System_Object___), т.е. не просто `new XElement("field", new XAttribute("value", x.TextBoxValue))`, а что-то вроде `x.TextBoxValue.Select(v => new XElement("field", new Attribute("value", v))).ToArray()`

Comment: Ну и, наверное, я бы не стал это записывать в виде одного огромного выражения, сделайте в 2 шага: 1) создали элемент `element` с атрибутам; 2) [**добавили** в него сабэлементы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.add?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Add_System_Object___). Будет читаться немного лучше.

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо вам большое! А можете оформить как ответ, чтобы в будущем кому-нибудь пригодилось.

Comment: @АндрейNOP по поводу сериализации, тоже об этом подумывал. Но я в этом деле новичок, честно говоря, а сериализировать можно только похожие по формату данные? Просто в будущем, в моей проге, в xml, данные будут совсем разного типа, в таком случае сериализацию не использовать или это не имеет значения разные или нет?

Comment: Сериализацию можно использовать с любыми данными. Напишите ответ самостоятельно, у меня, к сожалению, нету времени, чтобы проверить код.